# Improve rendering of PDFs compiling with pdflatex

Tags: pdftex

I have a pdf image (density plot)

[image]

If I open it with some pdf viewer (I have tested Max OSX preview, Acrobat reader) the figure looks fine, without white lines.
However, after compiling the TeX with pdf-latex, then white lines appear if I open de file with Skim or Preview programs and the white lines are there, but they do not appear when I open it with Acrobat reader.

Does anyone know how to remove the white lines in the pdf output for any pdf viewer?

Thank you very much for the help

Comment: Do the white lines appear when opening the original image in preview and zooming out until you have the same size as the image appears in the larger TeX pdf?

Comment: If I zoom-in the PDF with Preview or Skim they tend to disappear. After zoom-out to the original pdf size, the lines return. How could I fix this?

Comment: That was not my: Please open the **original** image and zoom **out** until it has the same size as it has, when you open the larger PDF and have the white lines appearing. What do you see?

Comment: Yes, with the original image, if I zoom-out the lines appear again. How should I fix this?

Comment: I see is not a pdf-latex render problem.

Comment: You see: The white lines have nothing to do with LaTeX, since they appear also *before* you compile the image within a .tex file. This is solely an artifact of the image and the limited capability of the PDF viewers to display scaled-down highly complex images.

Answer (score 1):

This should really be a comment but I haven't the required reputation yet. This is an artifact of the original image as Tiuri has helped you discover. I have had similar problems when I created pdf's using Matlab ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325901/matlab-how-to-avoid-artefacts-in-filled-contour-plots)). In my case:

> These white lines are the polygons defining the shaded areas which
>   have invisible edges, and don't quite overlap ([according to here](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/MathematicaGraphics.html#ExportShading)). The
>   problem is caused by the pdf viewer itself which tries to smooth the
>   lines displayed on the screen ([according to here](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/15388-artifacts-in-figures-exported-as-pdf-from-matlab))

Provided you have a similar problem to what I encountered you can avoid this in Acrobat Reader ([see here](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/15388-artifacts-in-figures-exported-as-pdf-from-matlab)) by fiddling with some settings, I cannot comment for Preview or Skim. If you are the one who generated the original pdf, using Matlab or whatever software which is creating the problem, I would recommend either saving as a .png or moving to another language like python. If I am completely off the ball let me know and I will delete this answer.

Comment: you are right. Acrobat displays the image well, not the rest of viewers. Thanks